# Confusion with outputs recieved when using random.choices() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
import random
lst = []
Background = ["Blue", "Orange", "Pink", "Purple", "Red", "Yellow"] 
background_weights = [18, 21, 10, 20, 9, 22]
for i in range(100):
    lst.append(random.choices(Background,weights= background_weights)[0])
blue=lst.count("Blue")
orange=lst.count("Orange")
pink=lst.count("Pink")
purple=lst.count("Purple")
red=lst.count("Red")
yellow=lst.count("Yellow")
print("blue","prob:",blue/100,"count:",blue)
print("orange","prob:",orange/100,"count:",orange)
print("pink","prob:",pink/100,"count:",pink)
print("purple","prob:",purple/100,"count:",purple)
print("red","prob:",red/100,"count:",red)
print("yellow","prob:",yellow/100,"count:",yellow)
```

and the following are the two different outputs i got

```
blue prob: 0.15 count: 15
orange prob: 0.23 count: 23
pink prob: 0.13 count: 13   
purple prob: 0.14 count: 14
red prob: 0.08 count: 8    
yellow prob: 0.27 count: 27
```

in the 1st output the choices seem correct as per my relative weighting.

2nd output

```
blue prob: 0.17 count: 17
orange prob: 0.26 count: 26
pink prob: 0.08 count: 8   
purple prob: 0.27 count: 27
red prob: 0.06 count: 6    
yellow prob: 0.16 count: 16
```

But when I ran it the 2nd time the output I received was not as per my relative weighting list as "yellow" is supposed to be chosen the most cuz I gave 22(the highest) as the weighting but in the 2nd output "purple" which has weighting only 20 is chosen the most.

Is this how it is supposed to be or is there some issue?  pls help me out

Comment: Look again at this line `print("blue","prob:",blue/100,"count:",blue)`.  The values will *always* match, because you use the same variable, `blue`.  I think you meant to print `background_weights[0]/100` instead of `blue/100`.

Comment: thx for pointing that out, i meant what u wrote.

Comment: When you flip a coin twice, are you surprised when you get two heads or two tails, instead of one head and one tail? THat's what `random.choices(["h", "t"], weights=[1,1])` simulates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing weird here. There is no guarantee that the value with the highest weight is generated the most in random samples.  If you generate 10000 samples then perhaps the fractions should be almost proportionate to the assigned weight, but there may still be some deviation.  In general, the fractions converge to the weight shares as you generate more and more samples.  This is known as the law of large numbers.